# Call a .NET dll that uses an unmanaged dll from Matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, dllimport, unmanaged

I have a library written in C# and it uses an unmanaged DLL. I need to use the .NET dll from Matlab using `NET.addAssembly().`

How can I do this?

Comment: What problem are you actually facing? What's stopping you simply using this assembly?

Comment: Thanks. I have a .net assembly with different methods some of which use a unmanaged dll. I want to use, in MATLAB, the .net dll but for that I need to have the unmanaged dll wrapped together with the .net one...

Comment: A month has passed. It's going to be hard to generate interest now. At the very least you need to edit the question to make it quite clear what you are asking.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I think I'm having the same problem. I can call a plain old C# lib from Matlab, but the second my assembly references an unmanaged lib, Matlab starts complaining that my classes have no methods or properties.